# How to handle csv mime type on windows machine

Tags: angularjs, excel, csv, mime-types

I am using an angular-file-upload to upload multiple files.I have a filter that allows only csv files to be uploaded. However this filter fails on windows (chrome and firefox) as csv files exported from ms-excel have mime type as "application/vnd.ms-excel" instead of "text/csv". How to handle this so that it works on cross-platorm and across all browsers?

Comment: can you please try adding accept=".csv,text/csv" ?